# Executing member function of class through pointer to abstract parent of said class

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-class, access-violation

I have created an abstract base class `Animal` which has public virtual abstract method `makeSound()`.  I created a subclass `Cow` which implements `Animal.makeSound()` as you would expect (you know... "moo").  And I have a `Farm` class which holds a private member variable `std::vector<Animal*> animals`.  In one of the `Farm` methods I iterate over all animals and make them make their sound.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++)
{
   animals[i]->makeSound()
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error

> Unhandled exception at 0x65766974 in
>   TestBed.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x65766974.

Any idea what's going on here?

---

UPDATE: adding more code per request

```
class Farm
{
public:
    Farm();
    virtual ~Farm(void);

    void setBarnOnFire();

private:
    vector<Animal*> animals;
};


Farm::Farm()
{
    animals.push_back(new Dog());
    animals.push_back(new Cat());
    animals.push_back(new Chicken());
    animals.push_back(new Horse());
    animals.push_back(new Cow());
}



Farm::setBarnOnFire()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++)
    {
       animals[i]->makeSound()
    }
}
```

### Is there something I'm supposed to do to initialize `animals`.

RESOLUTION:

So you were all correct.  I was accessing memory that I didn't own.  But it took me forever to track it down.  It was due to a misunderstanding about how object initialization takes place.  Basically, in an effort to "initialize" a member variable I was actually overwriting it with a local variable.  I then gave the local to all the animals that I created.  Later, the animals would try to call the local variable - which no longer existed.

Comment: You are trying to access memory that you don't own.  It could be caused by any number of problems.  If you post the rest of the code, I bet we can help :-).

Comment: I can't tell for sure without seeing the rest of the code any more than James can, but there's a red flag in the exception message:
`0x65 76 69 74` is four ASCII letters - `e v i t`.  It's a good bet you're trying to use the contents of a string as a pointer.

Comment: @Zack +1 for cool sleuthing.  Now if had spelled "evil" that would have been awesome.  Checking...

Comment: Where does the debugger break when the exception happens?  Have you posted that code?

Comment: even more code plz, specifically the decleration of Animal, and the decleration and body of the override versions of the function

Comment: @John:  The problem is most likely in the Animal hierarchy.  Please post the Animal and Cow classes.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is in one of the makeSounds() implementations?  Have you tried removing certain types of animals from the vector?  Does it always occur on one particular animal?  Does it always occur at a certain element position?

Comment: Learning how a debugger works... stay tuned everybody.  It seems that the general consensus is correct.  I just haven't gotten to the bottom of it.

Comment: It's really easy to identify ASCII letters in hex dumps because the first hex digit of each letter is always 4, 5, 6, or 7. I see `6*7*6*7*` and I break out the ASCII table.  ...Can you post the entire program, please?

Comment: If you're actually making a sound on the speaker, there must be some non-trivial code in the makeSound() functions.

You said, "Learning how a debugger works".  If you don't have a favorite, kdbg is good.  (http://www.kdbg.org/ and a manual at http://www.kdbg.org/manual ).

Comment: @cape1232 I'm just using the built-in visual c++ debugger.  It's pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, let me take a guess:

"Unhandled exception at 0x65766974 in TestBed.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x65766974."

it seems that the code pointer is being sent to 0x65766974  ("exception at 0x65766974") but this is not a valid place to be reading, let alone code: ("Access violation reading location 0x65766974", note, the same number)

so is it possible the vtable, or vtable pointer is being corrupted?
perhaps the object is being overwritten by a string?  as it is being stored in a vector, perhaps you have something overflowing a buffer (maybe a char array?) in the preceding object in the vector, and this is corrupting the next objects vtable pointer?